# CompositionTarget.Rendering not called?

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF, when I attempt to attach an event to CompositionTarget.Rendering, it never gets called. Why is this?

My intent is to measure the Frames Per Second (FPS) of a WPF application.

### Update

Go this working nicely, I can now measure the frames per second of my WPF app. See answer below.

Answer (score 4):

### This works

Attach the handler on the WPF dispatcher thread:

```
this.dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
    CompositionTarget.Rendering += this.WpfRenderFrameCallback;
});
```

### This will not work

```
CompositionTarget.Rendering += this.WpfRenderFrameCallback;
```

If you attempt to attach the handler on a background thread, then `this.WpfRenderFrameCallback` will never get called:

Comment: Where did you write this code? In `_Loaded`? In the constructor? How wouldn’t you already be on the GUI thread?

Comment: @binki This code can be anywhere, as long as it executes when the application is starting up. The point is that you have to attach the WpfRenderFrameCallback handler on the dispatcher thread, rather than on some background thread.

Comment: Just saying… the “This will not work” bit will work just fine as long as you use it from within a GUI event handler such as `_Loaded`. Using such a pattern allows you to be less verbose and use less code and fits better with the intended pattern, I think.